# How to keep app working even if model fails to load on Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

So, on my `ApplicationRoute` I'm loading a model to load some data which is common to the whole application. The workflow is as follow:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('config');
    },
    actions: {
        error: function(error, transition) {
            var self = this,
                renderErrorPage = function(template, disableMenu) {
                    self.render(template, {
                        into: 'application'
                    });
                    if(disableMenu) {
                        $('.menu > a').addClass('disable-menu'); // disable menu links
                    }
                },

            metadata = {
                'timeout': {
                    action: function(error, transition) {
                       BootstrapDialog.alert({message: 'Request Timeout!'});
                    }
                },
                'forbidden': {
                    action: function(error, transition) {
                        self.transitionTo('companies');
                    }
                },
                'unauthorized': {
                    action: function(error, transition) {
                        window.location.replace(error.responseJSON.redirect_url);
                    }
                },
                'bad gateway': {
                    action: function(error, transition) {
                        renderErrorPage('error', true);
                    }
                },
                'internal server error': {
                    action: function(error, transition) {
                        renderErrorPage('error', true);
                    }
                },
                'not found': {
                    action: function(error, transition) {
                        renderErrorPage('404', false);
                    }
                }
            };

            if(error.statusText.toLowerCase() in metadata) {
                metadata[error.statusText.toLowerCase()].action(error, transition);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So, if the user is not logged in, he gets an `unauthorized` 401 error which redirects him to the login page, and if he is logged in but still don't has access to this app, he gets a `forbidden` 403 error which just do a transition to `/#/companies/` where he'll register his company and then have access to the full app.

My problem is: this transition to `companies` is not happening since the model fails to load, and I have no idea of how to fix it.

Comment: This is a debugging problem, so I wind up asking questions for how I would debug it. When you say, "this transition... is not happening since the model fails to load," do you mean the `config` model you're trying to load on line 3?

Comment: yes, the `config` model.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should probably find a different way to load configuration than by a request to an authenticated API (or at least make an open version available for routes that don't require authentication, such as this error page). You may be able to get away with just using

```
if (isAuthenticated) {
    return this.store.find('config');
}
```

...and then setting `isAuthenticated` somewhere in the auth process.